Find the volume of the solid which is common to the right circular cylinders $x^2 + z^2 = 1, ~ y^2+z^2=1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$
Find the volume of the solid which is common to the right circular cylinders $x^2 + z^2 = 1, ~ y^2+z^2=1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.
I have tried several approaches but in all of them I get stuck on finding the limits in $z$ direction.
For $$-1 \leqslant x \leqslant 1$$ and $$-\sqrt{1-x^2} \leqslant y \leqslant \sqrt{1-x^2}$$  For $z$,  I divided it in three parts when $$-1 \leqslant x \leqslant -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},~ 
\sqrt{1-x^2} \leqslant z \leqslant \sqrt{1-y^2}$$  when $$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leqslant x \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, ~  \sqrt{1-y^2}  \leqslant z \leqslant \sqrt{1-x^2}$$ when  $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leqslant x  
\leqslant 1, ~ \sqrt{1-x^2} \leqslant z \leqslant \sqrt{1-y^2}$$
Please verify this.

Welcome to the site! Please use MathJax for writing the formulas. Here is a tutorial.
By the way I think you have typo on $y^2+2=1$

Are you sure you're copying the problem correctly? $x^2 + z = 1$ is a parabolic cylinder, not a circular one. And $y^2 + 2 = 1 $ is empty.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid#Tricylinder

$$x^2 + z^2 = 1,~y^2+z^2=1,~x^2 + y^2 = 1$$
I believe this is called the "Steinmetz solid"
Using cylindrical coordinates,
$x=r\cos\theta, ~y=r\sin\theta, ~z=z$
$0<r<1, 0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$
$0<z<\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $0<z<\sqrt{1-y^2}$ for $\frac{\pi}{4}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$
Our Jacobian is $r$
Therefore with all that information;
$$V=16\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-r^2\cos^2\theta}}(r)\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$$
$$\boxed{V=16-8\sqrt{2}}$$

